# User input and saving tables in Interactive SQL Java

Tags: sql, variables, interactive, substitution

I need help on two issues:

1) Getting user input for certain variables which I can substitute in the code later on.

```
define var = 12345
select * from table where var2 = &var .
```

But apparently define is not working in Interactive SQL. I tried without define too so that the variable can be taken as an input from user (I read some websites on google which suggested the same)

People with both SAS and SQL knowledge, essentially is there a macro variable equivalent in interactive sql.

2) I am writing a long SQL code and trying to rectify errors in the same using interactive SQL. 
I know how to save tables using the 'into' in SQL. But once the batch submission is done , these tables are not available for resuse. Is there a way to store the tables so that I do not have to run the complete code again and again as I troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

`define` and the `&var` syntax are SQL*Plus commands, they are not regular SQL commands.

In Java you can use a PreparedStatement to specify placeholders in your SQL:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("select * from table where var2 = ?");
stmt.setInt(1, 12345);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

I have no idea what you mean with "*saving tables using into*" and how that relates to your question.